# Android Studio without layout manager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to be able to make an app that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYjgl.jpg), but all of the layout managers get in the way. I either can't be precise enough with placing the numbers, or relative layout moves the other numbers out of place when I move one. What I want to know is if it's possible to not use any of the layout managers, and if so, how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom View:

```
public class CustomView extends View { ... }
```

You can then draw anything you want on its canvas in the onDraw method. Then View can can be used like any other View from an Activity or a Fragment.

```
onCreateView(...) {
    return CustomView();
}
```